# How to get user input to query?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I'm trying to get user's input value as query parameter.

Scenario is like this:

In my fragment, I have a textview that have onclick showing datepicker.
When a date picked, the fragment will show recyclerview with data which is stored in the database related to user chosen date.

Then I want to make query at dao something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `transaction` where date(//user chosen date) = transactionDate")
public List<TransactionEntity> getAllTransactions();
```

I just don't know how to pass that user chosen date from fragment to dao.
Or can I make query on the fragment instead?

I'm using room database, repository, and viewmodel in this apps.

Here is my fragment class:

```
public class Tab2Frag extends Fragment {
    private Tab2FragModelView tab2ViewModel;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;

    public Tab2Frag() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);

        final TextView dateChooser = rootView2.findViewById(R.id.dateChooserTV);
        String date_n = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        dateChooser.setText(date_n);

        dateChooser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                        android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_Alert,
                        dateSetListener, year, month, day
                );
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {

                // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
                cal.set(year, month, day);
                Date chosenDateDate = cal.getTime();


                // Format the date using style long and UK locale
                DateFormat df_long_uk = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK);
                String df_long_uk_str = df_long_uk.format(chosenDateDate);
                // Display the formatted date
                dateChooser.setText(df_long_uk_str);
                String dateIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                String dateVar = dateIn; //this is the var that I want to pass to query
            }
        };


        rootView2.findViewById(R.id.recView);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView2.findViewById(R.id.recView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        final TransactionAdapter adapter = new TransactionAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        tab2ViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Tab2FragModelView.class);
        tab2ViewModel.getAllTransactions().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                new Observer<List<TransactionEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<TransactionEntity> transactionEntities) {
                adapter.setTransaction(transactionEntities);
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView2;
    }
}
```

For now, i make my query like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `transaction` where date('now') = transactionDate")
    LiveData<List<TransactionEntity>> getAllTransactions();
```

I save the date as string in yyyy-MM-dd format like iso 8601

my entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "transaction")
public class TransactionEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "transactionId")
    private int transactionId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "transactionDate")
    private String date;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "transactionCategory")
    private String category;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "transactionDetail")
    private String detail;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "transactionAmount")
    private double amount;

    public TransactionEntity(String date, String category , String detail, double amount) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.date = date;
        this.category = category;
        this.detail = detail;
        this.amount = amount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in the parameter to the function like so:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `transaction` where date = :transactionDate")
public List<TransactionEntity> getAllTransactions(transactionDate);
```

**Edit from asker:**
I make my dao like this:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM `transaction` where transactionDate = :dateVar")
    List<TransactionEntity> getAllTransactionsByDate(String dateVar);
```

Turns out I need to tinker in my repo and modelView. This answer has helped me, thank you very much!

Comment: but how it will take user's chosen date from the fragment? is it happen automatically?

Comment: @ObedAdhinatapraya I would need to see your fragment code to determine that.

Comment: hello, sorry for slow respond. I put my fragment code in the question, kindly check.